# Trigger Instances in Skyrim

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In Skyrim there are several instances that occur randomly from bandits roaming around to Stormcloak guards roaming the roads. However there are better instances like dragons, Khajit traders and Noble Riders.

Is there a way to effectively trigger these events? There are some sources that indicate fast traveling over and over again. However all that does is just progress the time of the game. So naturally random events will spawn. But because Skyrim is an open world with events happening all the time is there anyway I can predict where these events will be? Or should I say "trigger them".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those events you are asking about are called [Random Encounters](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Random_Encounters_(Skyrim)) and they're not just tied to the passage of time.  There are specific locations where they are programmed to trigger.

Here is the relevant bit from the wiki:

> Random encounters can occur at a large number of pre-fixed locations scattered around the game world. Different encounters can occur at the same location, if it is revisited after some time has passed.

So if you find a location that spawns a random encounter, just travel back there once in a while to see if another one spawns.